# fetching data from db removes line breaks

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have text area and when the user submit the form I save the data into my db 
in db the line breaks work excellently but when displaying them back with echo the line breaks disappear :(
I check all things and removed all validation functions like strip_tags and so on just printed it pure from db but the same thing so can anyone tell me what went wrong ?
thnx in advance

Comment: use `nl2br( 'YOUR TEXT FROM DB' )`

Comment: also look at htmlspecialchars() http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php  (IE what If I enter `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`)

Comment: so accept the below answer from @PLB, if its helped you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaks in `textarea` is `\r\n` while for browsers it's just white-space. You need to replace them with `<br />` tag. php took care of it and you have [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function for that:

```
echo nl2br($stringFromDB);
```

**Note:** when you output user-input always escape it at first. So basically you should be doing:

```
// Chaining functions like this is bad. Avoid in real world apps.
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($stringFromDB, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```